# Define string/timestamp match a regex in Bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

I have to read from a file in bash script and always confirm that if the timestamp on each line is valid before doing anything. My timestamp looks like this:

```
Mar 15 14:20:48
```

I want to check if all timestamps I read will have the correct format. I tried doing it via:

```
(date -d ...)
```

But this tends to pass even if date looks like this: `Mar 15 14:2`

I was told to use regex to define what the date looks like so I was using this

```
if [["${LASTTS}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-3][0-9]+ [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ]]; then
```

But keep getting error saying `line 38: [[Mar 15 14:20:48: command not found`

Comment: space after `[[` isn't optional

Answer (score 2):

I believe it might be easier to ask `date` to do a conversion to the expected format and do a check if the input-date-format and the output-date-format is identical. If they are identical, the input-date-string is a valid string:

If you use the following command, it will convert the string to your valid format:

```
date -d "input-date" "+%b %d %T"
```

- In impossible input date will return an empty string:
- An invalid input date will return a different string

Examples"

```
input-date (d1) | output-date (d2)| d1 == d2 | input valid
----------------+-----------------+----------+-------------
Mar 15 14:02:15 | Mar 15 14:02:15 | yes      | yes
Mar 15 14:2     | Mar 15 14:02:00 | no       | no
Mar 32 14:02:15 |                 | no       | no
Mak 15 14:02:15 |                 | no       | no
Mar 15 24:02:15 |                 | no       | no
```

So your test would look like:

```
d1="Mar 15 14:20:48"
d2=$(date -d "$d1" "+%b %d %T" 2> /dev/null)
if [[ "$d1" == "$d2" ]]; then
   echo "the dates are the same"
fi
```

This method is a bit safer than using a regular expression as many strings might pass the regular expression but are not a valid date. A Simple example would be "XYZ 39 29:59:12"

In case of the OP's question, it would read:

```
if [[ "${LASTTS}" == $(date -d "${LASTTS}" "+%b %d %T" 2> /dev/null) ]]; then
```

Comment: How would I check if it is a valid timestamp format? I tried passing in Mar 15 14:2 and it still worked?

Comment: @JJAdams your statement is impossible. as the string `"Mar 15 14:2" is different from "Mar 15 14:02:00" (the latter is the outcome of `date` with the first as input).

Comment: After I pass in "Mar 15 14:2" and I echo the output of d2 It looks like this: Mar 15 14:02:00 which is a valid timestamp but what was read from the file is not. The point here is not to match them to each other but to make sure that it is of valid format i.e. Month Day Hr:Min:Sec

Comment: @JJAdams Exactly, that is why you perform the check. If "Mar 15 14:2" is different from the string stored in `d2`, you know that the input date has the wrong format. And this because you ask specifically to put it in the correct format. If the input string would already be correct, it would be a one-to-one operation and they would be identical.

Comment: @JJAdams I have updated it a bit in the hope to make it a bit clearer. My idea is **not** to convert the input string to a valid string and use the latter, my idea is to do the conversion to check if it is a valid string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your format is always the same as "Mar 15 14:20:48" if correct, then it should always match `+'%b %d %T'`. If so, you can verify not only the format but the content with `date`.

```
$: ts='Mar 15 14:20:48' # valid date/time in correct format
$: [[ "$ts" == "$( date +'%b %d %T' -d "$ts" )" ]] && echo ok || echo mismatch
ok
$: ts='Mar 15 14:2' # valid date/time in wrong format
$: [[ "$ts" == "$( date +'%b %d %T' -d "$ts" )" ]] && echo ok || echo mismatch
mismatch
$: ts='Feb 31 14:20:48' # invalid date/time in correct format
$: [[ "$ts" == "$( date +'%b %d %T' -d "$ts" )" ]] && echo ok || echo mismatch
date: invalid date ‘Feb 31 14:20:48’
mismatch
```

Comment: Apologies, this appears to just be another telling of [kvantour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8344060/kvantour)'s already proposed solution, but it was fun to do. :)

Comment: One small caveat - this will fail if run against a file created on leap day of a previous year, I think... but that's just a weakness of the timestamp format, and won't matter if not run in a non-leap year.